# Morse interatomic potential

Tags: intermolecular-forces

I am working with Morse interatomic potential, I searched through the Internet but I could not find any Morse parameters for Zirconium element. Is there any table, handbook or something like these which list these parameters? or Is it possible to calculate these parameters for hcp metal elements?

Comment: Since the Morse potential was constructed to model diatomic bonding, it seems a bit of a stretch to easily generalize it to a crystalline potential, be it hcp, fcc, etc. So, it seems unlikely that one will find a readily available table.

Comment: In principle, one can perform quantum chemical calculations on the zirconium crystal structure and distort it to obtain Morse potential parameters. However, this is a lot of work even for an expert and may even provide the answer OP is looking for, presuming they do not care for the parameters but want to find some property using it.